# Dispatching actions in namespaced stores (Vuex/Nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm having a problem accessing actions in namespaced stores in a Nuxt SPA.
Let's say I have a store file in the store directory called *"example.js"*:

```
import Vuex from "vuex";

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({ 
      state: {
        forms : [],
      },
      mutations: {
        setForms(state, forms) {
          state.forms = forms
        }
      },
      actions: {
        setForms(vuexContext, forms) {
          vuexContext.commit("setForms", forms)
        }
      },
      getters: {
        getForms(state) {
          return state.forms
        }
      }
    })
}

export default createStore;
```

Then on some page I try to fetch data an put it into the store:

```
  async fetch(context) {
    return axios.get(..)
      .then(data => {
          context.store.dispatch("example/setForms", data.data) 
      })
      .catch(e => {
        context.error(e);
      });
```

That gives me:

> unknown action type: example/setForms

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `example.js` is a bit wrong it should look like:

```
//store/example.js

export const state = () => ({
  forms: [],
});
export const mutations = {
  setForms(state, forms) {
    state.forms = forms;
  },
};
export const actions = {
  setForms(vuexContext, forms) {
    vuexContext.commit("setForms", forms);
  },
};
export const getters = {
  getForms(state) {
    return state.forms;
  },
};
```

And use it like:

```
  fetch() {
    return axios
      .get(...)
      .then((data) => {
        this.$store.dispatch("example/setForms", data.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        context.error(e);
      });
  },
```

Comment: thanks! I picked up this other form of notation somewhere in a tutorial and didn't use any getters and setters before, so I never ran into this problem

Answer (score 0):

Please add `namespaced: true` to your store. So:

```
const moduleA = { 
      namespaced: true,
      state: {
        forms : [],
      },
      mutations: {
        setForms(state, forms) {
          state.forms = forms
        }
      },
      actions: {
        setForms(vuexContext, forms) {
          vuexContext.commit("setForms", forms)
        }
      },
      getters: {
        getForms(state) {
          return state.forms
        }
      }
}


const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    a: moduleA
  }
});


export default store;
```

so you can use it as `$this.store.commit("a/setForms");`

Comment: that's what Nuxt is supposed to do